# Download file by Javascript postback in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, post

EDIT:
I´ll be more specific. I want to do a script to download a group of files every day. 
To do this programmatically, i need to click in a javascript button.
It´s simple when is just put the URL in WebRequest class, but in javascript button i don´t have the URL. How can i mount this URL?

**Request (by Fiddler):**

```
POST /SomeSite?Something.aspx HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://www.Site.com/Stackoverflow/SomeSite?Something.aspx
Accept-Language: pt-BR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.Site.com
Content-Length: 10616
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: idioma=pt-br; WT_FPC=id=187.16.81.13-3324702672.30186643:lv=1320587789589:ss=1320587578749

__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24contentPlaceHolderConteudo%24lnkDownloadArquivo&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%BlaBlaBla
```

Comment: Download a file with javascript? And what do you intend to do with this file once you fetch its contents on the client?

Comment: That question doesn't make much sense. can you clarify?

Comment: What is the application for this? More details would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see the _EVENTTARGET that is using postback with a link Button which name is "lnkDownloadArquivo". So far I understand you want to simulate same download request without button click. if so then you can check here a solution .
http://ciintelligence.blogspot.com/2011/01/fetching-aspnet-authenticated-page-with.html.
 here you can get idea how asp.net button post back request works.

Comment: I used fiddler to get the request body and used the code bellow to write parameters: StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
            sw.Write(parameters);
            sw.Close();

Answer (score 0):

The built-in class you need is the `HTTPWebRequest` (or `WebRequest`) class. To create one, call `System.Net.WebRequest.Create()` and pass your URL, add the appropriate headers using the `Headers` collection, write to the `Stream` retrieved from `WebRequest.GetRequestStream()`, then retrieve the response using `WebRequest.GetResponse()`. From the retrieved response object, you can get the response `Stream` using `WebResponse.GetResponseStream()`. The `Stream` can then be read from like any other `Stream` object.

Comment: But i don´t understand how can i download using eventtarget and eventargument

Comment: @Makah: What *are* you talking about?

Comment: I´m trying to download from a javascript button. I don´t know how to build the post

Comment: @Makah: Well, that's a problem! Just get the stream, and write out the data. If the POST data is in key/value pairs format, you write it out the same as GET, really: `hello=world&one=two`. And that's what it it is, according to your example request...